# Server load average soaring+network usage 5X up on production server, need quick help

Tags: linux, php, load-average

My main app server is experiencing unprecedented peak in network usage and load average.

The server is on Ec2/Scalr running php+memcache the graphs shows this kind of load has never happened before and that the load average builds up in hours see here: http://imm.io/56Jy
I didnt change anything that could have this effect.

Additional info: 
PHP Version 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10
Linux ec2-50-17-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com 2.6.16-xenU #1 SMP Mon May 28 03:41:49 SAST 2007 i686

How can I detect what is causing it?

Comment: have you run tcpdump to capture the source and type of network traffic?

Comment: Did you checked apache logs, any anomaly? If you can stop apache and see if the server load drops. I would also check sendmail in case of misconfiguration there is an open relay.

Comment: I would also check for a crawler. Get yourself a robots.txt file incase you don't have one because sometimes Google/MS crawlers can cause this kind of behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the startpoints ! 
Re crawler- this is a web service with no in links and no content. its not a crawler.
Re-tcpdump - going to try it! thanks for the tip.
Re-Apache logs - going to check.
I feel that some processes just hang and they keep accumulating quietly. since the load is going up slowly and steadily in the last 24  hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the AWS meltdown....